# Why I'm getting recyclerview's item position as "-1"?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a very strange error . Basically I'm trying to delete recyclerview items on LongClick but in some cases I'm getting `adapter position` as `-1`.

My Code:

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


 Message message = mMessages.get(position);
 holder.setMessage(message.getMessage());

  holder.msgContainer.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
  int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

  mMessages.remove(position);
 notifyItemRemoved(position);
 notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mMessages.size());


    return false;
   });

 }

 }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: RecyclerView does not handle any adapter updates until the next layout traversal. This may create temporary inconsistencies between what user sees on the screen and what adapter contents have.

This is a common issue, just wrap your call in an if statement checking if the position isn't -1.

```
if (getAdapterPosition() != - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

getAdapterPosition() return -1.It means Adapter gets a NO_POSITION,and it always happened when you call method like notifyDataSetChanged(). we always use position like this

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


  Message message = mMessages.get(position);
  holder.setMessage(message.getMessage());

  holder.msgContainer.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
 //you can use the position  parameter directly，just set it as final
  mMessages.remove(position);
  notifyItemRemoved(position);
  notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mMessages.size());
     return false;
   });
}
```

Comment: Sir, by following your method now I'm getting ** java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5** error

Comment: There's a problem with logic.For example,There are 10 item in your RecyclerView,if you want to remove a item clicked,you should return the recyclerview's size as 8( it means 9 item)，then call notifyDataSetChanged( ).If you think it is difficult to use "final psoition",you can edit log in your code.